# Unable to render title field on node template

Tags: theming

For my content type - Article I have a template

```
node--article.tpl.php
```

I currently render other fields such as the body text just fine. However the title cannot be displayed.
I'm using

```
print render($content['title']);
print render($content['body']);
```

But only the title is displayed. To make sure I'm using the right machine name, I looked at the content type configuration.

[image]

Is there something missing? Or is there something special I have to do to to the 'title' field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to print the title using

```
print $title;
```